# Super weird HTML mess up

Tags: php, sql, css, html

I have a comment system, it works by adding a row to a SQL database. Anyway That works, but then when I echo out the comment div gets all messed up.. Anyway here is the page it is on: http://learntc.net/index.php.

PHP:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($count==1)
    {
      $bg == "33383C" ;
      $count = 0;
    }
    echo "<div style='background-color: $bg; border: 1px soild silver;' class='comment'>";
    echo "<div class='imageAndName'>";
        echo "<img src='". $row["image"] ."' class='cPic'/>";
        echo "<div class='UserLink'><a href='" . $row["page"] . "'>" . $row["username"] . "</a></div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='textStuff'>";
        echo "<div class='post'>" . $row["comment"] . "</div>";
        echo "<div style='color: gray; font-size: 8px'>" . $row["date"] . "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";

    $bg = "#282C2F";
    $count = $count + 1;
}
```

CSS:

```
.comments{
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #454D53;
}
.cPic{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
.imageAndName{
    width: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left
}
.imageAndName a{
    display: block;
}
.textStuff{
    width: 70%;
    float: right;

}
.post{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.comment{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `clear: both` to your `.comment` style.

Comment: Well, said Jonathan. @Jordan clear is a special css property that basically says where other floating elements are not allowed.

Comment: Jordan, people often use this when they have multiple divs inside another container div to stop crazy html/css problems.

Answer (score 1):

Problem one:

```
$bg == "33383C" ;
```

should be

```
$bg = "#33383C";
```

I don't see anything else. The div is probably screwed up for this reason.